# Creating separate alias for the same column in SQL?

Tags: sql, select, nested

I want to select the same column and store them under separate aliases so that I can display certain values from the column separately.

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName AS Customer_Name,
(SELECT CategoryName FROM Categories) AS Cate,
(SELECT CategoryName FROM Categories) AS Cate2
FROM Customers
```

This is what I've tried doing, but it only returns one value from the CategoryName column?

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_inner_prod

I've linked an online DB that contains the DB I'm working with.^

I want to be able to see all the values from CategoryName in Cate1 and Cate2 when I run the query.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired output? It looks like you may simply want a cartesian join if you're trying to show every possible combination.

Comment: `customer` would need to be joined to `order` which would need to be joined to `orderdetail` which would need to be joined to `product` which would need to be joined to `categories` in order to establish the relationship between the customer and the categories they purchased. You can't just sling table names around in sql and hope that the database will know how to join them for you. If "list the categories the customer has purchased and pivot the results" isn't the desired results you are after, please clarify. Your non-working sql isn't clear enough for us to discern.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that questions here are expected to be self-contained, most people here will skip the question if they are supposed to follow link to some external source.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it looks like you want to group all categories for each rows. Below query will select all customer and also group all categorynames for each row.

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName AS Customer_Name,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Distinct CategoryName) FROM Categories) AS Cate,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Distinct CategoryName) FROM Categories) AS Cate2
FROM Customers
```

Find below output of the query in MySql (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_inner_prod).

[image]

Comment: @jarlh, updated answer. Above query will execute fine in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like you're trying to do a cartesian join but in an unusual method. If so, then I would simply with this...

---

```
with customers as (
  select 'Tony' as CustomerName union all 
  select 'Sarah' union all
  select 'Chih'
  ), 
 categories as (
  select 'color' as CategoryName union all 
  select 'odor' union all
  select 'weight'
   )
 select 
  cus.CustomerName, 
  cat.CategoryName as cat1, 
  cat.CategoryName as cat2
 from customers cus, categories cat;
```

| customername | cat1 | cat2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tony | color | color |
| Tony | odor | odor |
| Tony | weight | weight |
| Sarah | color | color |
| Sarah | odor | odor |
| Sarah | weight | weight |
| Chih | color | color |
| Chih | odor | odor |
| Chih | weight | weight |

---

But if you are seeking something different, then you should update your question with sample data and desired output, all formatted as text.